# Find the number of three sums in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, hash

If you are given a list

```
numList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

and you are asked to find the number of three sums that add to a particular number

```
target = 10
```

How you could come up with the answer?

For example, the combination of : `[1,3,6], [1,2,7], [2,3,5], [1,4,5]` 
would result in a return value of `4`.

I know how to use a hashing based function to come up with the one three sum for the solution using the code below but am not sure how to add all unique three sum solutions.

```
def find3Numbers(A,arr_size,sum): 
    for i in range(0,arr_size-1): 
        #Find pair in subarray A[i+1..n-1]  
        # with sum equal to sum - A[i] 
        s = set() 
        curr_sum = sum - A[i] 
        for j in range(i+1,arr_size): 
            if (curr_sum - A[j]) in s: 
                print("Triplet is", A[i],  
                        ", ", A[j], ", ", curr_sum-A[j]) 
                return True
            s.add(A[j]) 

    return False
```

Comment: Looks like a homework question but `itertools.combinations` comes to mind here...

Comment: Note: it is a bad idea to use variable or argument names that hide python's builtin types or functions (e.g. an argument called `sum`).

Answer (score 2):

Using [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
from itertools import combinations

numList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

def check(value):
    return sum(value) == 10

filtered = list(filter(check, list(combinations(numList, 3))))
print(filtered)
#[(1, 2, 7), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 5)]
```

Combinations finds all possible combinations, then I just filtered it down to only the ones that added up to 10

Answer (score 1):

You just need to tweak your solution to count the solutions rather than returning after the first solution is found:

```
def find3Numbers(A,arr_size,sum):
    count_sums = 0

    for i in range(0,arr_size-1): 
        #Find pair in subarray A[i+1..n-1]  
        # with sum equal to sum - A[i] 
        s = set() 
        curr_sum = sum - A[i] 
        for j in range(i+1,arr_size): 
            if (curr_sum - A[j]) in s: 
                count_sums += 1 # Count here
            s.add(A[j]) 

    return count_sums # Finally return the count
```

---

Note this is not to say your algorithm is now correct. Moving on, you may want to use a counting set rather than a regular set for `s`. See [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).